Why does Allah not give me hadayah, when I clearly want to get back to him and leave sinful life?
I have prayed multiple times to Allah to forgive me and help me to leave the sins. I promised but broke those promises again and again. I want help from him but don't get the help. I try to leave sins but fall into them again. Then, i feel the instant regret after doing the sins. Then, I pray and the cycle continues. But i am unable to leave these sins forever. What am I missing out? What should I do? Do sins lower the chances of taubah being accepted?
